# Select multiple records by short query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
function comp_post_code($comp_post_code){
global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); ///*** for error handling
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * from uk_data where 
comp_post_code like :comp_post_code and cat1 like :cat");
$STH->bindValue(':cat', "%$cat1%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindValue(':comp_post_code', "%$comp_post_code%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $STH;
}
```

i have  cat1 to cat10 .. i want to get data output without  writing long code like

```
 and comp_post_code like :comp_post_code and cat2 like :cat
 and comp_post_code like :comp_post_code and cat3 like :cat
```

i there way out for this ...we can write ong code and get out put but still wanna know can we do with some other way ?

Table Structure

comp_post_code 
cat1 
cat2 
cat3 
cat4

Comment: can you post the table structure? (cat1.. cat10 are table columns?)

Comment: @FlorinelChis yes thy are and i have Edited question ...

Comment: :cat should be found in *all* cat[1-n] or in *any* of the column?

Comment: @FlorinelChis i am making search,  if post code is like B91% and cat is in any cat(from cat1 to cat 9) it should come in output ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details from your comments:

```
SELECT * from uk_data where 
comp_post_code like :comp_post_code AND (
cat1 like :cat OR
cat2 like :cat OR
cat3 like :cat OR
cat4 like :cat OR
cat5 like :cat OR
cat6 like :cat OR
cat7 like :cat OR
cat8 like :cat OR
cat9 like :cat OR
cat10 like :cat
)
```